# Problems importing data in Stata using "file" and a local macro

Tags: import, stata

I'm attempting to import data from a number of log files.  Here's how I'm approaching it:

I have the log files in a separate directory and I generate a txt file with the list of filenames in that directory.  I then read through that txt file and subsequently use the filenames in a loop with an import command to bring the data in.  This process worked when I last run the do file about 6 months ago and now it's not working.

The basics of the code look like this:

```
cd "filepath\logs\"
! dir cpuusage*.log /a-d /b /o:-d >"filepath\filelist.txt"

file open myfile using "filepath\filelist.txt",read
file read myfile line

import delimited using `line', delim(" ") varnames(nonames)
```

The result of that import command is (0 vars, 0 obs) despite the fact that filelist.txt has a list of 14 filenames.

I'm a novice so I'm really hoping there's something simple and obvious that I'm overlooking.  I still don't understand why this exact method worked six months ago...  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do your filenames in filelist.txt have embedded spaces? If so, your import delimited command needs to add quotation marks thusly `"\`line'"`.

Comment: The implication of this is the `import` command was accepted as legal but thinks it found an empty file. It's hard to understand that without seeing your files. Try typing the file using `type` just before you try to `import`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `fs` for this:

```
cd "filepath\logs\"
fs cpuusage*.log
foreach f in `r(files)' {
    import delimited using `f', delim(" ") varnames(nonames)
}
```

It's hard to help more without knowing what your log files look like. I would suggest trying to import one using the menu to get the syntax right.

Comment: `fs` is from SSC and must be installed by `ssc install fs` before you can use it.